# Fixed size element based on screen resolution

Tags: html, css

I want to deliver webpages containing of two divs, which are fixed size (does not depend on browser window size). However, the size should be different for different screen resolution (1920x1080 vs 1440x900). Essentially if the user maximize the browser window, he will see the whole webpage.

An example:

For 1920x1080: div will have width 1600
For 1400x900: div will have width 1000

What would be the easiest way to do this?

```
#group {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 300px; left: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    width: 410px; height: 440px;
    background: black; 
    display:inline-block;
}

#batch {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 10px; right: 10;
    bottom:0; left:420px; 
    width: 1225px; height: 820px; 
    background: black; 
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the desired result, but I think media queries can help.

Comment: `the size should be different for different screen size` ...... `the size doesn't depend on browser window size`. sorry, your explanation is confusing to me.

Comment: _the size doesn't depend on browser window size_ you mean you want to show 1920px version if I have 1920px monitor **regardless of whether the browser window is maximized or not**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use media queries based on screen size.  Something like the example below.

```
/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
    /* Custom CSS GOES HERE */
}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
    /* Custom CSS GOES HERE */
}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
    /* Custom CSS GOES HERE */
}

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
    /* Custom CSS GOES HERE */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you need to use media queries that use [`min-device-width`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#device-width):

```css
body::before {
  content: "tiny screen";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
@media screen and (min-device-width: 1024px) {
  body::before {
    content: "1024px or higher";
  }
}
@media screen and (min-device-width: 1366px) {
  body::before {
    content: "1366px or higher";
  }
}
@media screen and (min-device-width: 1440px) {
  body::before {
    content: "1440px or higher";
  }
}
@media screen and (min-device-width: 1920px) {
  body::before {
    content: "1920px or higher";
  }
}
```

```html
<center>
  <p>The screen size reported above will not change when you resize the browser.</p>
</center>
```

Note: you are supposed to put your CSS rules inside those blocks.